# Ivy browning leaves

Tags: english-ivy

I've had this ivy for years now, and repotted it last month, as it was with some other plants and the pot had gotten too small, not to mention the soil needed changing. 
After the "operation", its leaves started going brown and falling off. I thought it was just shock from the transplant, as its roots had tangled up with those of a parlor palm and it was hard to separate them without some damage. However, it's still browning, and now I'm worried about it. It seems to be growing new leaves from the parts where it lost some, but some of the new growth then goes brown again... 
What's going on? And how do I fix it? [image][image]

Comment: Is that all there is of the ivy plant, just one long stem?  And is there anything else in the same pot other than what looks like a Campanula  variety? Is there drainage in the pot? And is this indoors or out, or have you moved it from outdoors to inside,or the other way around? A photo of the whole pot showing the plants might be useful too,if you can add one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy is usually a VERY resilient and fast-growing plant that will root in pretty much anything: throwing its cuttings to the compost is not advised because there's a high chance that they'll take roots there as well. Since your plant has started to brown despite repotting (a VERY rare sight where I come from), I'd suspect a major general nutrient deficiency. Since you haven't mentioned pruning the plant (which needs to be done regularly in outdoor conditions, it's quite an obnoxious weed in the temperate climate gardens in fact) I'd say you could try pruning the roots a bit. Also make sure you don't overwater the plant, because (as unlikely as it might seem in the case of ivy)  browning is probably indicative of overwatering too.

Comment: Sadly, the ivy died before I could find out what is wrong with it. And yes, one of the problems with googling anything about ivy is that usually, the advice is about how to get rid of it, rather than how to keep it growing and healthy.

Comment: Yeah, this is almost unheard of. Perhaps it had a pest in its soil or something.